# Thread-Safety with Enumerable collections and copies

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections

Imagine I have an interface `IHeapObject`:

```
interface IHeapObject
{
    string Id {get;}
    SomeEnum Type {get;}
}
```

and it's implementation `HeapObject`:

```
class HeapObject : IHeapObject
{
    public string Id {get; private set;}

    public SomeEnum Type {get; private set;}

    public object objectLocker {get; } = new object();
}
```

Imagine I have a class that has a `public IEnumerable<IHeapObject>` Readonly-Property property.
This property points to a `private readonly IList<HeapObject>` field. Like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public IEnumerable<IHeapObject> Foo => _bar;

    private readonly IList<HeapObject> _bar;
}
```

Suppose the way I handle this collection inside of this class is 100% thread-safe. Furthermore, any and all state changes in the list and HeapObject itself happen only within this class.
Is the fact that I'm exposing the collection a thread-safety concern?

My assumptions is that I can't guarantee that the `IHeapObject` instance will be "up-to-date" when read from outside `MyClass`. Meaning, as long as I don't rely on the properties' values for critical processes outside of it, I should be fine. Is this assumption correct?

Secondly, is there a risk of throwing an exception while iterating over the `IEnumerable` collection from outside of the class?

Comment: Why do you have `public string Id {get; private set;}` twice?

Comment: Thread safety and iteration-safe collection modification are related but different concepts.  Problems (exceptions) involving the latter occur even with single threaded programming.  Search "modify a collection while iterating".

Answer (score 1):

The basic thread safety rules state that there can be multiple readers *or* a single writer, but not both at the same time.

You allow anyone to be a reader. You cannot control who is. Therefore, it is actually *never* safe to write to the structures.